# Update database when some entries were removed JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I'm developing a logic in the server side of my project that will update an Entity in the database. But this entity has reference to a list of another entity.

So, for example I have an Entity `Test` like this one:

```
    @Entity
    public class Test {

        @Id
        @Column(name = "idTest", nullable = false)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;
        private String name;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "idTest", targetEntity = Test2.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private Collection<Test2> test2Collection;
    }
```

which has references to `Test2` Entity.

```
@Entity
public class Test2 {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "idTest2", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String field1;
    private String field2;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idTest", referencedColumnName = "idTest")
    private Test idTest;
}
```

In my case, I'm updating the Collection `test2Collection` of `Test` entry and eventually I'm removing some of `Test2` entries of it.

The simple `merge` method from `EntityManager` does not detect that some entries has been deleted when I call it passing the new updated `Test` entry.

I was thinking to track the removed entries from `test2Collection` by making a diff between the `Test` entry before updating the database with the new `Test` entry to be updated.

But I'm not sure this is the only (and best) way of doing this. Anyone else has another idea?

Comment: Don't you just need for example "cascade = CascadeType.ALL" on the OneToMany?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your relationship, you have to add orphanRemoval, then if you remove one element of the collection and persist Test, the element deleted on the collection will be automatically delete of the Test2 table.

```
@OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "idTest", targetEntity = Test2.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Collection<Test2> test2Collection;
```

Comment: Thanks! This approach is way better than the one I thought!